# Can a kafka Stream join have more that two topics that can be joined together

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have the below example which will consume these two topics -> "test-topic-A" and  "test-topic-B" perform a join and then output to a new streamed topic -> "test-topic-Streamed", this work very well but is it possible to ***join more than two topic into a single stream***? I have a .py script that acts as a producer and another .py script as a consumer
Python Producer console:
**Key produced -> test-key-join
Topic produced -> test-topic-A
Data in topic -> Producer 1 left topic
{'status_code': 200, 'error': None}
message sent successfully...
Key produced -> test-key-join
Topic produced -> test-topic-B
Data in topic -> Producer 2 right topic
{'status_code': 200, 'error': None}**

Python Consumer console:***strong text***
**ConsumerRecord(topic='test-topic-Streamed', partition=0, offset=82, timestamp=1659716723171,
timestamp_type=0, key=b'test-key-join', value=b'LEFT="Producer 1 left topic", RIGHT="Producer
2 right topic"', headers=[], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=13, serialized_value_size=60,
serialized_header_size=-1)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


private final static String outputTopic = "test-topic-Streamed";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-pipe");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9093"); //
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());  

final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
System.out.println("Stream-Stream Inner Many Topics Join Example \n ");
KStream<String, String> leftSource = builder.stream("test-topic-A");
KStream<String, String> rightSource = builder.stream("test-topic-B");

KStream<String, String> joined = leftSource.join(rightSource, (leftValue, rightValue) -> "LEFT=" + leftValue + ", RIGHT=" + rightValue, /* ValueJoiner */
  JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5)),//ofMinutes(5)),
  Joined.with(
      Serdes.String(), /* key */
      Serdes.String(), /* left value */
      Serdes.String()) /* right value */
        
);
// Output the stream 
joined.to(outputTopic);    
       
//Create the Kafka Streams instance
final Topology topology = builder.build();
final KafkaStreams streams= new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);


Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    streams.close();
    latch.countDown();
  }
});

try {
  streams.start();
  latch.await();
} catch (Throwable e) {
  System.exit(1);
}
System.exit(0);


 }//End Main
```